# How to use grep/awk/sed to print until a certain character?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am a complete beginner on shell scripting and I am trying to iterate through a set of JSON files and trying to extract a certain field out of it. Each JSON file has a *"country:"xxx"* field. In each JSON file, there are 10k of the same field with the same country name so I need only the first occurrence and I can do that using "-m 1".

I tried to use grep for this but could not figure out how to extract the whole field including the country name from each file at first occurrence.

```
for FILE in *.json;
do   
        grep -o -a -m 1 -h -r '"country":"' $FILE;
done
```

I tried to use another pipe and use the below pattern but it did not work

```
| egrep -o '^[^"]+'
```

Actual Output:

```
"country":"
"country":"
"country":"
```

Desired Output:

```
"country:"romania"
"country:"united kingdom"
"country:"tajikistan"
```

but I need the whole thing. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `Each JSON file` so use a JSON parser, not grep.

Comment: please edit question with explicit attended result

Comment: Please indicate the output you _want_. Are you asking for a unique set of countries from your input files? Or do you only want to return the first country from _each_ file? The output you currently get is because you specify `-o` - that will only output the matched part of the string, not the rest of the line

Comment: @arco444 I only need the first country from each file. If I remove -o, I get a lot of things because there are other fields after the country field.

Answer (score 0):

There is one general answer on the question "I only want the first occurence", and that answer is:

```
... | head -n 1
```

This mean, whatever your do: take the head (the first lines), the `-n` switch gives you the possibility to say how many you want (one in this case).

The same can be done for the last occurence(s), but then you use `tail` instead of `head` (you can also use the `-n` switch).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can already get the first occurrence using "-m 1".

Comment: @Cugomastik: you need to drop the `-o` from your grep: this only shows the regular expression, while you need the whole line, containing the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things. I found the pattern I was looking for.

```
grep -Po '"country":.*?[^\\]",' $FILE | head -n 1;
```